# Singleton to factory in PHP

Tags: php, class, singleton, factory

There are many topics about this already, but I have not a clear picture of why factory patterns are better practice than Singleton.

**An example**

```
class MySingleton {
 public static function numberByWhat( $number ) {
   return $number + 100;
 }
 public static function someCharacters( $string ) {
   return $string + 'abc';
 }
}

class MyOtherSingleton {
  public static function getImage( $url ) {
    return '<img src="' . $url . MySingleton::numberByWhat( $50 ) . '">';
  }
  public static function getTextById( $id ) {
    if( $id == 3 ) {
      return 'this is my text' . MySingleton::someCharacters( 'Yeah' );
    }
  }
}

function run() {
  echo MyOtherSingleton::getImage( 'http://www.example.com/image.png' );
  echo MyOtherSingleton::getTextById( 3 );
}

run();
```

So there we have 2 classes and a function. When I `run()` I start a function in the second class. Inside the functions in the second class there are calls to the first class.

- How would this look like as a factory pattern?
- Why is it better as a factory pattern?

Comment: This neither looks like factory nor singleton patterns. You simply have some functions grouped within some classes, for now. It becomes hard to test the state of your class instances.

Comment: `Factory` creates some objects. Where in your code do you have objects?

Comment: You can get rid of classes entirely in this example and go with simple raw global functions. The only thing classes are adding here is a sliver of namespacing. You're nowhere actual OO territory, and hence the question makes little sense.

Comment: While your question is a little bit off, I'm thinking, from some incorrect assumptions, I've tried to explain both of these patterns as well as another relevant pattern in my answer. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So the examples you've given are neither Singletons nor Factories. What you have here are simply "static classes"--classes with only static methods and properties. Factories and Singletons don't really solve the same problem, either, so it's difficult to compare and contrast them.

## Singletons

A [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) is used to manage shared state or avoid the overhead of instantiating a class multiple times when you only really need "one of something".

Here's an example of a Singleton:

```
class DatabaseConnection {
    // Static reference to the single instance of this class we maintain.
    protected static $instance;

    // Normal instance properties.
    protected $mysql;

    // Protected constructor to prevent "new DatabaseConnection();"
    protected function __construct() {
        $this->mysql = new MySQLConnection("localhost", 3306, "appdb");
    }

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (!self::$instance) {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function query($sql) {
        return $this->mysql->query($sql);
    }
}
```

Whenever you want to use the `DatabaseConnection()` in your code, you do it like this:

```
function getUser($userId) {
    $userData = DatabaseConnection::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM ...");
}
```

The `DatabaseConnection()` is only instantiated once, starting the first time it is used. There will never be more than one created.

## Dependency Injection / Inversion of Control

The competing strategy to using a Singleton is, basically, [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) or [Inversion of Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control). With Dependency Injection, instead of having one shared, staticly-stored instance of a class, the instance is simply passed from class to class and function to function. Here's a simple example:

```
class DatabaseConnection {
    // Normal instance properties.
    protected $mysql;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->mysql = new MySQLConnection("localhost", 3306, "appdb");
    }

    public function query($sql) {
        return $this->mysql->query($sql);
    }
}

class UserManager {
    protected $databaseConnection;

    public function __construct(DatabaseConnection $databaseConnection) {
        $this->databaseConnection = $databaseConnection;
    }

    public function lookupUser($userId) {
        return $this->databaseConnection->query("SELECT ...");
    }
}
```

One advantage of Dependency Injection is that you can test your code much more easily. You could, for example, extend `DatabaseConnection` and call it `TestDatabaseConnection`, and make it not actually use a real MySQL database, which can make your tests faster and more reliable. So, the debate is really between Singletons and Dependency Injection / Inversion of Control, not Factories.

## Factories

So, now, [Factories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern): Factories simplify the creation of objects, return objects of different classes/subclasses, and help to create objects from "templates". As an example, let's say we have different classes to represent different types of users:

```
class User {
    // ...
}

class ModeratorUser extends User {
    // ...
}

class AdminUser extends ModeratorUser {
    // ...
}

class GuestUser extends User {
    // ...
}
```

Each of these classes contain methods and properties that would be useful for working with a certain type of user account. So, how would you create and return one of these user objects by User ID, ensuring that the correct type of user is returned? We can use a factory pattern:

```
class UserFactory {
    public static function fromUserId(DatabaseConnection $db, $userId) {
        $record = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id ...");
        // ...

        switch ($record['type']) {
            case 'admin':
                return new AdminUser($userId);
                break;

            case 'moderator':
                return new ModeratorUser($userId);
                break;

            case 'guest':
                return new GuestUser($userId);
                break;

            default:
            case 'normal':
                return new User($userId);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, to load the proper `User` class, you'd just call:

```
$user = UserFactory::fromUserId($userId);
```

If it's an admin account, it will be an `AdminUser`; if it's a guest account, it will be a `GuestUser`.

Comment: So in the last one... static function calls an extended class which uses a kind of base class. It's the probably the most simple example I've seen so far. I will probably combine static functions with extended classes from now on.